# Use centered variables or include an intercept in time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, interpretation, vector-autoregression, intercept, multivariate-regression

I have read that analogous to univariate AR(p) models, there are two possibilities to allow for a non-zero mean with VAR(p) models:

a) either use centered variables in the model:
Φ(B)(Xt − μ) = Zt

b) or include an ‘intercept’ in the regression:
Φ(B)Xt = v + Zt

Is there any difference in interpretation when using the first or second approach in the context of time series analysis?